# Specifying the Path in a C++ Program

Tags: c, windows, dll, path

I am writing a Java launcher in C for windows that launches against a Java Runtime Environment that is located in my program's directory (i.e. is distributed with my program). I have code that works (specified below), but it needs `jvm.dll` to be in its %PATH% in order to execute.

I would like to add a line to my code that tells the program to check in `<executable's directory>/jre/bin/server` for `jvm.dll`, so the executable can be run just by double clicking.

Right now when I run it, it says "The program can't start because jvm.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program  to fix this problem."

If I move my simple executable into `jre\bin\server` where `jvm.dll` resides and try to run it, it works. **So I just need to tell my program to search in a specific other place for the dll and I'll be good to go.**

Based on something I found by searching around, I tried `HINSTANCE hVM = LoadLibrary("jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");`. Unfortunately, that does not work.

How can I accomplish this goal?  I'm not a C programmer or a Windows programmer, so apologies if the question is basic.

```
#include <jni.h> 
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
   HINSTANCE hVM = LoadLibrary("jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll"); //Does not work

   JavaVM *jvm; 
   JNIEnv *env;
   JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; 
   JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];

   int index = 0;
   options[index].optionString = (char *)"-Djava.class.path=./main.jar";

   vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_10;
   vm_args.nOptions = 1;
   vm_args.options = options;
   vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
   JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
   delete options;

   jmethodID main = NULL;
   jclass cls = NULL;

   cls = env->FindClass("net/joshuad/test/Main");
   if(env->ExceptionCheck()) {  
      env->ExceptionDescribe();
      env->ExceptionClear();
   }

   if (cls != NULL) {
      main = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
   } else {
      printf("Unable to find the requested class\n");
   }

   if (main != NULL) {
      env->CallStaticVoidMethod( cls, main, " ");
   } else {
      printf("main method not found") ;
   }

   jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In order to link to an embedded JRE this way, we need to [link explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/784bt7z7(v=vs.140)) rather than implicitly, so our program doesn't try to link up before running, and then call `JNI_CreateJavaVM` with a function pointer rather than with a function call directly.

**Fair Disclaimer -- I am a terrible C++ programmer and although this works, I have no idea if it's using good practices. Use at your own risk.**

Here is a working example for anyone else who might be trying to do this:

```
#include <jni.h> 
#include <windows.h>

typedef UINT (CALLBACK* JVMDLLFunction)( JavaVM**, void**, JavaVMInitArgs * );

    int main() {        
        HINSTANCE jvmDLL = LoadLibrary(".\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");

        if ( !jvmDLL ) {
             printf("failed to find jvm.dll at specified location, exiting.\n");
             return 1;
        }

        JVMDLLFunction createJavaVMFunction = (JVMDLLFunction)GetProcAddress(jvmDLL, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

        if ( ! createJavaVMFunction ) {
             printf("Failed to get pointer to JNI_CreateJavaVM function from jvm.dll, exiting\n");
             return 1;
        } 

        JavaVM *jvm; 
        JNIEnv *env;
        JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; 
        JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];

        int index = 0;
        options[index].optionString = (char *)"-Djava.class.path=./main.jar";

        vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_10;
        vm_args.nOptions = 1;
        vm_args.options = options;
        vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

        createJavaVMFunction( &jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args );

        //JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
        delete options;

        jmethodID main = NULL;
        jclass cls = NULL;

        cls = env->FindClass("net/joshuad/test/Main");
        if(env->ExceptionCheck()) {  
          env->ExceptionDescribe();
          env->ExceptionClear();
        }

        if (cls != NULL) {
          main = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        } else {
          printf("Unable to find the requested class\n");
        }

        if (main != NULL) {
          env->CallStaticVoidMethod( cls, main, " ");
        } else {
          printf("main method not found") ;
        }

        jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The given path will work only if you program is written in same directory that contains jre folder. Otherwise You will have to specify the full location for example "C:\\jdk\\jrebin\server\\jvm.dll"

Comment: Yes, my program is located in a folder which contains a subfolder named 'jre' which contains the entire java runtime environment. I am distributing a JRE with my program.

Comment: I am not really sure how this answer's the question.